# Ошибка 400 Bad Request при попытке авторизоваться на Papirus.net (API) через Python

Tags: python, post, request, rest

Пытаюсь сделать запрос на авторизацию в систему Papirus.net по [этой инструкции](https://www.papirus.net/api#bkauth). Но все попытки приводят к неудаче, а именно - `400 Bad Request`.

Код следующий:

```
import httplib, json

params = json.dumps({"ClientID": "myid",
                     "Login": "myname@somedomain.ru",
                     "Password": "mypwd"})

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n',
           'Content-Length': 123}
url = 'https://papirus.net/restapi/accesstoken'
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('papirus.net', 443)
conn.request('POST', url='/restapi/accesstoken', body=params, headers=headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
conn.close()
```

Ну соответственно `clientid`, `login` и `password` указал иные.

После запуска - ошибка:

```
400 Bad Request
{"ApiException":{"Code":"Unspecified","Message":"A connection error occurred. Please try again later."}}
```

Данные заголовки мне посоветовали сделать в поддержке Papirus'а. Больше подсказать ничего не могут!

Comment: Зачем вы Content-Length руками пишете? Если там расхождение хотя бы в один символ, то запрос будет обрезан.

Comment: Запрос, кстати забыл указать, идет такой:
{"Login": "myname@somedomain.ru", "Password": "mypwd", "ClientID": "myid"}

Ну вообще мне этот заголовок посоветовали в поддержке Papirus'а...
Хорошо, убрал его.

Теперь ошибка та же, но с другим пояснением:

400 Bad Request
{"ApiException":{"Code":"BadFormat","Message":"There was an error deserializing the object of type Papirus.PublicApi.Requests.AccessTokenParams. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: ClientID, root."}}

Comment: @fixatorika, Насколько я понимаю, их парсер json не получает последние символы.

а) попробуйте все-таки послать Content-Length, но со значением `len(params)`  
б) если и так не выйдет, сделайте простенький сервер на локалхосте (или еще где, неважно), который будет отлавливать запрос и писать его в чистом виде (заголовки + тело) в файл, возможно, сам запрос почему-то режется.  
в) наиболее идиотское решение проблемы - допишите в конец params несколько пробелов, возможно, это решит проблемы с длиной.

Comment: Смастерил простой серверок, который принял такой вот запрос

    POST /restapi/accesstoken HTTP/1.1
    Host: 
    Accept-Encoding: identity
    Content-Length: 121
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    
    
    {"Login": "myname@somedomain.ru", "Password": "mypwd", "ClientID": "myid"}

К сожалению выставление Content-Length со значением len(params) не помогло. И пробелы в конце params тоже.

Comment: @fixatorika, я написал ответ, там вообще не на стороне клиента ошибки. Content-Length, кстати, должен нормально обсчитываться сам, не берусь утверждать, но о нем наверняка можно вообще в будущем не думать.

Comment: <p><a href="/users/16095/fike">@Fike</a>, безумно прерад за помощь, но к сожалению сервер по прежнему шлет `400 Bad request`.</p>

Answer (score 2):

Если еще будете общаться с техподдержкой, шлите им лучи ненависти:

```
Request Body  
{  
    "ClientId": "1234abcd-1234-abcd-1234-abcd1234abcd",  
    "Login": "bill.smith@somedomain.edu",  
    "Password": "******"  
}
```

Этот пример означает, что их парсер не понимает json простой строкой. Им обязательно нужен символ новой строки с одной из фигурных скобок (я так и не разобрался, с какой, но это неважно). На питоне это решается простым параметром `json.dumps`:

```
params = json.dumps({"ClientID": "myid",
                     "Login": "myname@somedomain.ru",
                     "Password": "mypwd"}, indent=4)
print params
```

(вывод)

```
fike@aves:~/Temp/python/shorts$ python papirus.py 
{
    "Login": "myname@somedomain.ru", 
    "Password": "mypwd", 
    "ClientID": "myid"
}
401 Unauthorized
{"ApiException":{"Code":"AuthorizationErrorInvalidLoginOrPassword","Message":"Invalid user name (email) \/ password"}}
```

Ненависть / смешная третья опция

Comment: А вот тут начинается самое интересное!)
При запросе с такими параметрами "myid","myname@somedomain.ru", "mypwd", indent=4
действительно выходит такая ошибка 401 Unauthorized

НО! При верных параметрах:
   
    params = json.dumps({"ClientID": "********--************",
                         "Login": "************@*****.**********.ru",
                         "Password": "********"}, indent=4)
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

прежняя ошибка 

    400 Bad Request
    "A connection error occurred. Please try again later."

Вот так, и в чем подвох...

Comment: @fixatorika, вот это уже вряд ли кто-то кроме поддержки сможет пояснить. Судя по тексту ошибки (если это все, что он выдает), проблема может быть опять на их стороне. Возможно, заголовки почему-то не нравятся, но у них в доке ни слова про это.  
Кстати, информацию о запросе можно увидеть, вызвав `conn.set_debuglevel(1)`, после этого информация о запросе будет выводиться в stdout.

Answer (score 0):

[@Fike](/users/16095/fike), действительно, проблема была со стороны сервиса. Как выяснилось в запросе нужно было указывать параметр ClientId, а не ClientID. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь! Пример полностью рабочий)